# How can I add the "Ken Burns Effect" to Swiper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

I know it is possible to add the "Ken Burns Effect" to Swiper because I have seen it on this website:  https://novibuilder.com/page-slider.html (about two-thirds of the way down).  They provide the HTML code but not the CSS nor JS files that make it work.

Can anyone help me add the Ken Burns Effect to Swiper?  I want to keep in the realm of free and open source.

HTML:

```
  <div class="swiper-container swiper-slider swiper-scale-effect"> 
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

      <div class="swiper-slide slide1">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide slide2">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide slide3">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide slide4">Slide 4</div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      centeredSlides: true,
      effect: 'fade',
      autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
    .swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;


  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.slide1 {
background-image: url(images/bg_1.jpg);
background-position: center; 
}
    .slide2 {
background-image: url(images/bg_2.jpg);
background-position: center; 
}
    .slide3 {
background-image: url(images/bg_3.jpg);
background-position: center; 
}
    .slide4 {
background-image: url(images/bg_4.jpg);
background-position: center; 
}
```

Not sure what to do to get the scaling effect working.  The images do fade into each other as they should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done using CSS:

```
.swiper-scale-effect .swiper-slide-cover {
  transition: 8.5s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.swiper-scale-effect .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-cover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

... which means: when `.swiper-scale-effect` gets the class `swiper-slide-active` (which is what happens when the slide becomes active), if the slider has `swiper-scale-effect` class, the `.swiper-slide-cover` will transition from `scale(1.08)` to `scale(1)` over a period of time of `8.5s`.

To change the way the slide pans (it's actually scaling), you need to control the `transform-origin` property of that respective slide.

I don't think that's part of the slider itself. On that website it's part of a huge custom CSS file: `style.css` (has `44.338` lines).

---

Here's an example:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  effect: 'fade',
  autoplay: {
    delay: 8500,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

```css
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide > .swiper-slide-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}
.swiper-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.swiper-slide .slide1 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=670);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}

.swiper-slide .slide2 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=837);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.swiper-slide .slide3 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800/400?image=947);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.swiper-slide .slide4 {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/750/250?image=945);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.swiper-scale-effect .swiper-slide-cover {
  transition: 10s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.swiper-scale-effect .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-cover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper-container swiper-scale-effect">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide1 swiper-slide-cover"></div>
      <div>Slide 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide2 swiper-slide-cover"></div>
      <div>Slide 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide3 swiper-slide-cover"></div>
      <div>Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="slide4 swiper-slide-cover"></div>
      <div>Slide 4></div>
    </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

    <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic and marked as the accepted answer.   I have to work out a few bugs.  I see it works perfectly in the "run code snippet" but when I plug it into my site, the images are just thin bars instead of filling the page.   Just a CSS issue, I imagine and will be sorted out with a little diligence!

Comment: You need to adjust the `transform-origin` for each slide specifically, as I did in the answer, in order to alternate their movement and give each of them the effect you want. The movement should differ from slide to slide. It also helps if the original images are cut close to the ratio of the slide.

Comment: Well....I cannot sort it out.  The images appear as thin horizontal bars...stacked vertically.  I can see that they are zooming as they should, but notting I do makes them fill the screen.  I have toyed with position settings, z-index settings all to no avail.....wish I could post a screen shot....

Comment: Can you provide a link? I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I uploaded the files to dropbox.  One is the plain site....with just the slider only.   The second one is my site, with the files integrated.  MY SITE: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qpr0ocke29evgi4/AAAQl5C6QKpMM-NY6TwgG8vBa?dl=0    PLAIN:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e333i0idw8c6qs0/AADSnU9Q4Reym2w5aknFjYPna?dl=0

Comment: What you provided is far from making sense as a webpage. It's missing resources (fonts, js, images and stylesheets - try to download what you provided in a different folder and open it). I'll make it simple: if you can't produce a [mcve], you should consider hiring professional help. You're stretching the limits of "open source" here, to put it elegantly.

Comment: Of course.  I was just trying to just post the essentials.  This is a PagePiling based webpage.  I am not looking for advice on the final design and look of the site.  Just the mechanics "under the hood" to make sure everything works before I start plugging in all of the images and fonts, etc.   You have been enormously helpful and pleasant up until now  Your above message however was uncharacteristically unpleasant.   If I annoy you for some reason, please just ignore my post.

Comment: You asked me o provide a link, and I did.  The link contained all of the files (css, images, js).   If you had asked me to create a MCVE on this site, I would have done that.  I am confused at this sudden change of tone.....

Comment: The change of tone was when I realized you simply copy/pasted what I provided, expecting it to work, which leads to the conclusion you don't understand much of it. In your case, because you want the slider to be as big as the viewport, you're supposed to tweak the CSS to your needs. Long story short, here is the code you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/dmjgft4q/

Comment: And, as I also said, you have now commented twice on how the site "looks".  I stated ( and will now re-state) that my method is to get everything working before I add final pictures and fonts.  So yes, it's damn ugly and may seem unfinished.....because IT IS.  You may think this is the work of someone unskilled, but you are wrong to come to this conclusion.  BUT since you actually helped, despite your unpleasant comments and accusations, I THANK YOU.

Comment: *"Ugly"*, just like *"beautiful"* are subjective terms. I have not commented on the aesthetics of your web-page and I have no intention to. If you want to thank me, please do it by not assuming you know what I think. Happy holidays!